# How to handle large number of MySQL rows from using Cron scripts

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a PHP Cron script that will fetch all threads from a forum section and iterate to see if they meet some criteria (e.g if they are older than 2 years).

Typically I would do:

```
SELECT DATE_CREATED FROM `threads`
WHERE BOARD = board_id
AND (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(DATE_CREATED)) >= 2
```

and then loop accordingly.

Now there is the tendency that there may be 1,000,000 or more threads meeting this criterion.

Initially, I thought that there wouldn't be any need to limit the rows returned since it's a Cron script

Now I figured that there may be some memory issues when the rows returned becomes really really large.

This is where I need help on how to effectively loop through thousands of MySQL records in a PHP script that will be executed by Cron job.

I have thought of using LIMIT and then iterating over it as paginated content, but I want to know if there is a more effective way to do it; hopefully on MySQL server only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to LIMIT and loop through, so that the return is smaller for every iteration. Do it in parts!

Comment: you can use limit and the offset in order to loop through a smaller part of the results. Otherwise, why not to split the where clause and repeat the query, let's say once per month?

Comment: Thanks I do will as suggested. @Sissy please how do you propose I do that

Comment: You could change your code to process just one month at a time and repeat for each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- First solution - using limit and offset would be something like (pseudo code):

```
//get total number of rows
$total_rows = $db->$query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `threads`
WHERE BOARD = board_id
AND (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(DATE_CREATED)) >= 2");

//put in your array or wherever you need 1000 rows at a time
for($i = 0; $i < $total_rows/1000; i++){
   $array << $db->query("SELECT DATE_CREATED FROM `threads`
   WHERE BOARD = board_id
   AND (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(DATE_CREATED)) >= 2
   LIMIT ($i+1, $i+1)*1000");
}
```

2 - solution: getting rows month by month, considering you have only two years (let's say 2016-2017) for the sake of simplicity you could do something like

```
$base_year = 2016;
//nest loops for the years and for the months
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
   for($j = 0; j < 12; $j++){
      $array << $db->query("SELECT DATE_CREATED FROM `threads`
       WHERE BOARD = board_id
       AND YEAR(DATE_CREATED) = ($i + $base_year)
       AND MONTH(DATE_CREATED = ($j+1)");
   }
}
```

hope this help you find the right and more suitable way to you.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't going to be a base year. It will be running on yearly basis referencing the date threads were created. A user can create threads at anytime then when next the Cron runs it searches for threads that are 2 years or more old

Comment: well you can get the base_year with php datetime whenever the cronjob is executed.